# Should Akka Cluster number of shard should be always equal number of Kafka partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream, akka-cluster

I am currently working with Akka Project consist of an 5 Node Akka Cluster. When we first setup the project, we decided to set number of shards to 50 mainly because of the statement in the following link.

[Akka Cluster Sharding](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster-sharding.html)

> As a rule of thumb, the number of shards should be a factor ten greater than the planned maximum number of cluster nodes

Now we are changing our messaging solution to Kafka and if I read the documentation correctly at the akka stream kafka, they are advising to take same number of shards as the number of partitions.

We don't want to have 50 partition in our topics, so I will probably go 5 partition (equal to the Akka Cluster Nodes) that would mean reducing number of shards in the Akka Cluster from 50 to 5.

Is this a bad idea? Would this have negative effect on the Akka Cluster to have so few shards?

Thx for answers...

Comment: Can you please add link to the documentation that advises to `take same number of shards as the number of partitions.`

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/cluster-sharding.html may be I am interpreting the text wrong but here it is >> Therefore it’s critical to use the same Kafka message key (sharded entity id) and number of Kafka topic partitions (shards). The message extractors can optionally look up the number of shards given a topic name, or the user can provide the number of shards explicitly

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that that guideline only applies if you're using the optional external shard allocator described in that link.  If you're using the "normal" shard allocator, then the normal Cluster Sharding advice applies.

The following things are true of using Cluster Sharding, whether using Kafka or not:

- The number of shards should never be less than the number of nodes in the cluster on which you want to host sharded entities (otherwise, some nodes of the cluster will be unused)
- In general, the more shards you have, the more evenly the workload will be spread (thanks to the law of large numbers), but each shard does add some coordination overhead (i.e. there are diminishing returns to extreme shard counts)

The Kafka external shard allocator for Cluster Sharding can be used when message serialization or other network bottlenecks are causing a substantial degradation in performance.  You can use the "normal" shard allocator (regardless of the number of shards) when consuming from Kafka, and you can even switch between them (as with anything that involves changing the number of shards, you must ensure that at no point do any two nodes in the cluster disagree on the number of shards or the means of determining the shard key: this means that such changes require a full cluster restart) to evaluate which better suits your needs.

I tend not to use the Kafka external shard allocator: to me the fact that my processing scalability is basically decoupled from the Kafka partition count (this is especially relevant if multiple services are consuming from the same topic).  Additionally, if the actors responsible for the processing are receiving messages ingested from multiple topics, then the external shard allocator may not even deliver much benefit.

A lot of people in my experience forget that performance and scalability are not the same thing: very often changes to improve performance will limit scalability and changes to improve scalability will impose a performance penalty.  The external shard allocator to be a pretty good example of a change to improve performance which limits scalability.

Comment: I understand your points but I have additional complications, I have several Actor dependant from Business Case that has to work together. So as illustration, I have ActorType1, ActorType2, ActorType3, ActorType4, ActorType5, who will participate a Business Case. What I am planning to do, kafka topics that delivers messages for these Actor will have keys like following, ActorType1uuid1_token1, ActorType2uuid1_token1, ActorType3uuid1_token1, ActorType4uuid1_token1, ActorType5uuid1_token1 and with special Kafka Partiioner I will make sure that they will land in the same Topic Partition and with

Comment: partition count being same as shard number all the Actor Entities that have to work together will land in the same shard. This way I hoping that I will not pay the price of the serialisation and inter Akka Node communication. If it works as I plan, lets say in a 5 Node Akka Cluster, for ex, AkkaClusterNode3 -> shard3 ->  (ActorType1uuid1_token1,  ActorType2uuid1_token1,  ActorType3uuid1_token1,  ActorType4uuid1_token1,  ActorType5uuid1_token1) so inter Cluster Node communication is prevented for accomplishing this Business Case.

Comment: If I don't follow this plan what I fear, again in a 5 Node Akka Cluster, Actors may distribute as following, AkkaClusterNode1 -> shard4-> ActorType1uuid1_token1, AkkaClusterNode2 - shard12->ActorType2uuid1_token1, AkkaClusterNode3 -> shard26 ->ActorType3uuid1_token1, AkkaClusterNode4 -> shard32 -> ActorType4uuid1_token1, AkkaClusterNode5 -> shard35 -> ActorType5uuid1_token1 and to complete a Business Case every Node has to communicate with another Node then I really start the pay the price of the Serialisation and inter node communication, I start not to scale linearly. If I add node 6 I scale

Comment: If you use the external shard allocator with a 5-partition topic, you won't scale at all beyond 5 nodes, because every node beyond 5 won't be used at all.  You can ensure that the different `ActorType`s for the same token hash to the same shard by hashing only the token.

Comment: we have no problem to go 10 partitions or 20 or 50, if it is necessary to scale (there is nothing limting that in our partitioning strategy), I was just didn't want to go directly to 50 and I was not sure because of wording in the ClusterSharding (AkkaNode*10) , so 5 being to low, because of the wording at KafkaClusterSharding (partitionsizde=numberofshards)

Comment: Increasing partitions of a Kafka topic is not something that should be done lightly (for some usecases, it's something that should never be done).

Comment: (The usecases where you cannot increase the partitions of a topic once the topic has been written to are basically the usecases where you care about the ordering of messages for a given key you're partitioning by and you cannot tolerate a downtime longer than the topic retention period)